# ¿Cómo hacer fetch de un raw de un archivo JSON alojado en una Realtime Database de Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native

Tengo una función que me recupera marcadores de mapas desde un archivo RAW que estaba alojado en GitHub.

Ahora que tengo la app terminada, estaba trabajando para poder hacer lo mismo desde el servidor de Firebase, pero no he logrado descubrir cómo recuperar la información de la misma manera como lo hacía desde un archivo de GitHub.

Esta es la función que recupera los marcadores de mapa:

```js
getStations() {
    return fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com...')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < responseData.features.length; i++) {
          if (responseData.features[i].properties.Torwand != '<Null>') {
            var coords = responseData.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
            var obcn = responseData.features[i].properties.obcn;
            var bikesToTake = responseData.features[i].properties.bikesToTake;
            var spacesToLeft = responseData.features[i].properties.spacesToLeft;
            var status = responseData.features[i].properties.status;
            var marker = {
              coordinate: {
                latitude: coords[1],
                longitude: coords[0],
              },
              title: obcn,
              description: "Estado: " + status + " Bicicletas: " + bikesToTake + " Espacios: " + spacesToLeft
            }
            markers.push(marker);
          }
        }
        this.setState({
          markers: markers,
          loaded: true,
        });
      }
      ).done();
  }
```

Mi idea era reemplazar la URL del archivo RAW de GitHub por algo similar de Firebase, pero la documentación es poca y no hay algo sobre archivos RAW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días Christopher,

lo primero tienes que tener el paquete de firebase instalado en tu proyecto.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/firebase

```
yarn add firebase
```

ahora tienes que tener un proyecto creado en Firebase y un fichero en tu proyecto con la configuración, por ejemplo Firebase.js y dentro el siguiente código con tus datos.

https://firebase.google.com/

```
export default (firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "********",
  authDomain: "********",
  databaseURL: "********",
  projectId: "********",
  storageBucket: "********",
  messagingSenderId: "********",
  appId: "********"
});
```

Y hacer la inicialización del firebase te recomiendo que lo hagas en el app.js

```
import firebaseConfig from "./app/utils/Firebase";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Ahora vamos a imaginar que tenemos en firebase una colección con los datos de tu fichero.json, simplemente tendríamos que ejecutar la siguiente linea para coger todos los elementos.

```
function getElements() {
    const collection = firebase.database().ref().child('features');

    this.collection.on('value', snapshot => {
        let arrayFeatures = [];
        snapshot.forEach(row => {
            arrayFeatures.push({
                id: row.key,
                properties: row.val().properties,
                geometry: row.val().geometry,
            })
        });
    })
}
```

De esta manera sacarías toda la colección completa.

Un saludo.